# Error: Class 'Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\Helper\ConfigHelper' not found

Tags: magento2, aws

I did setup:di:compile with this and getting this error.
Error: Class 'Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\Helper\ConfigHelper' not found in /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
Although it was working before.
Anything I might be missing here
Here is the link to store
http://13.127.125.33/

Comment: Hi there , can you please check if the class is actually present in this path - 
Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\Helper\ConfigHelper.php and who are all calling and using this class ? , there may be cases that "Algolia_AlgoliaSearch" module be disabled , but some other module is calling and using that ,in this case you should use "sequence" the module.xml file , because of this the object wont be created.Or there may a case that class itself is not present.Please check and let me know.Thanks

Comment: which path are you talking about this folder does not exist app/code directory.This module is enabled even if i disable it the error remains the same?Any Ideas why this might be

Comment: Again the same answer, please find from your editor in all places of this project which modules are using this class - "Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\Helper\ConfigHelper", because even after you disable this module, the error remains the same, the reason is the same only. Thanks

Comment: I think there is some other issue the agolia search is on so module is active.The class is not generated properly or maybe i am not setting the permissions properly.it was working properly on other server.